# Error publishing Lambda Function in VS 2017

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-2017, aws-lambda

When I try to publish my Lambda project in Visual Studio I get an error message:

**"... publish PATH\ProjectName does not contain a project.json file"**

I did some reading, it would seem in the new Visual Studio (2017) there is no longer a project.json file in because .Net Core is now based on msbuild, which means that it's going to use *.csproj instead of project.json. Package!

How am I supposed to publish my Lambda function via Visual Studio if I don't have the project.json file available?

PS. I have latest AWS Toolkit installed.